# R data.table binary value for last row in group by condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have data like this:

```
library(data.table)
id <- c("1232","1232","1232","4211","4211","4211")
conversion <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1)
DT <- data.table(id, conversion)

id   date         conversion
1232 2018-01-01   0
1232 2018-01-03   0
1232 2018-01-04   0
4211 2018-04-01   1
4211 2018-04-04   1
4211 2018-04-06   1
```

I would like to create a binary value for only the last row of each group based on the id row.  The binary would 1 only when conversion is 1 for the group.

```
id   date         conversion  lastconv
1232 2018-01-01   0           0
1232 2018-01-03   0           0 
1232 2018-01-04   0           0
4211 2018-04-01   1           0
4211 2018-04-04   1           0
4211 2018-04-06   1           1
```

I've tried using a few examples with the "mult" parameter in data.table, but have only returned errors.

```
DT[unique(id), lastconv := 1, mult = "last"]
```

Comment: Your example would sort of worked if you had ```setkey``` before doing your line. Note that ```mult = "last"``` would result in 1 being placed on the id 1232 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timings for reference:

```
library(data.table)
#data.table 1.12.3 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2019-05-12 17:04:48 UTC; root using 4 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
set.seed(0L)
nid <- 3e6L
DT <- data.table(id=rep(1L:nid, each=3L))[,
    conversion := sample(c(0L,1L), 1L, replace=TRUE), by=.(id)]
DT0 <- copy(DT)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)

mtd0 <- function() {
    DT0[DT0[, .I[.N], by=id]$V1, lastconv := conversion]
    DT0[is.na(lastconv), lastconv := 0L]
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    DT1[DT1[, .I[.N], by=id]$V1, lastconv := conversion]
    setnafill(DT1, cols = "lastconv", fill = 0L)
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    DT2[, v := 0]
    DT2[.(DT2[conversion == 1, unique(id)]), on=.(id), mult="last", v := 1]

    #or also
    #DT2[, v := 0L][
    #    DT2[,.(cv=last(conversion)), id], on=.(id), mult="last", v := cv]
}

mtd3 <- function() {
    DT3[ , lastconv := as.integer(.I == .I[.N] & conversion == 1), by = id]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2(), mtd3(), times=1L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 mtd0() 1363.1783 1416.1867 1468.9256 1469.1952 1521.7992 1574.4033     3  b 
 mtd1() 1349.5333 1365.4653 1378.9350 1381.3974 1393.6358 1405.8743     3  b 
 mtd2()  511.5615  515.4728  552.9133  519.3841  573.5892  627.7944     3 a  
 mtd3() 3966.8867 4009.1128 4048.9607 4051.3389 4089.9977 4128.6564     3   c
```

Answer (score 5):

For each id, check if row number is the last row number in the group, and if 'conversion' is 1. Convert logical result to integer.

```
DT[ , lastconv := as.integer(.I == .I[.N] & conversion == 1), by = id]
```

Answer (score 5):

Modifying the OP's code to join on the last row of each group:

```
DT[, v := 0]
DT[.(DT[conversion == 1, unique(id)]), on=.(id), mult="last", v := 1]

     id conversion v
1: 1232          0 0
2: 1232          0 0
3: 1232          0 0
4: 4211          1 0
5: 4211          1 0
6: 4211          1 1
```

This is only different in that it selects which `id`s to edit based on the desired condition.

Answer (score 4):

Filter for the last row per group and set `lastconv` equal to `conversion`.

```
DT[DT[, .I[.N], by=id]$V1, lastconv := conversion]
```

Then replace `NA`s with `0`

```
DT[is.na(lastconv), lastconv := 0L]
```

Result

```
DT
#     id conversion lastconv
#1: 1232          0        0
#2: 1232          0        0
#3: 1232          0        0
#4: 4211          1        0
#5: 4211          1        0
#6: 4211          1        1
```

---

If `data.table` v1.12.3 is installed we could also use the new function `setnafill` to replace `NA`s in the second step

```
DT[DT[, .I[.N], by=id]$V1, lastconv := conversion]
setnafill(DT, cols = "lastconv", fill = 0L)
```

Comment: great to see users posting recent features! thanks, some more info on this new feature in [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) file, or in [manual](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/nafill.html)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
library(tidyverse)

final_conversion_dat <- DT %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         final_conversion = ifelse(date == max(date, na.rm = T) & conversion == 1, 1, 0))
```